# Create item in list based on condition

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Hi I have two lists List A and List B. In list A I have a persons field (assigned To). I want to allow the user to create item in List B only if he/she is the the person in the Assigned To column.

On List B the Assigned To has visitor access. I dont want to add access to all the people who could be in the Assigned To as then the wrong person could create the item.
Basically if you are nominated in List A then you can create items in List B only.
Can this be done ?

I'm currently creating items in List B with CSOM Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option is to create a group and title it `ListBCreators`. Give necessary permission to this group for creating items in List B

Now when you add item in List A, you can have a workflow or CSOM code to put the user in `Assigned To` to the group `ListBCreators`.

Comment: Sorry, I think I missed something, The Assigned To person in a List A item can create an Item in List B and is locked to that person alone (apart from admin) .

Comment: Ok I am not getting the complete picture. For what I understood.. Using CSOM you can break inheritance of the item in List B. And then enable user in Assigned To field.

Comment: Hi What you suggested works, I've added a group to List B (ListBCreators) that contain posible people who can contribute, when that person adds an Item to List B the wf removes permisions of item and adds permission specifically for the person (Assigned To). It does the job but small problem, anyone in the group can do this, I wanted the item created if its the nominated person in ListA only. There is a link on an aspx page which displays List A and List B, The link opens a csom code to create items in list B, perhaps the best is to hide the link ?